# How to set center image width in RoyalSlider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I have [this page](http://scharc.com/scharc30/de/project/norsborgdepan/) with a [RoyalSlider](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/visible-nearby/) in it in the Visible Nearby Images mode.

I would like to change the size of the center image to 1050x514 to reproduce the slider seen on [this page](http://www.tobinproperties.se/projekt/skivillage-funasdalen/) .

These are my settings for the slider:

```js
var si = $('#gallery-1').royalSlider({
   addActiveClass: true,
   imageScaleMode: 'fill',
   arrowsNav: false,
   controlNavigation: 'bullets',
   autoScaleSlider: true, 
   autoScaleSliderWidth: 940,     
   autoScaleSliderHeight: 460,
   loop: true,
   fadeinLoadedSlide: false,
   globalCaption: true,
   keyboardNavEnabled: true,
   globalCaptionInside: false,
   slidesSpacing:0,
   controlsInside : false,

   visibleNearby: {
     enabled: true,
     centerArea: 0.5708,
     center: true,
     breakpoint: 704,
     breakpointCenterArea: 1,
     navigateByCenterClick: true
   }
 }).data('royalSlider');
```

I can't seem to find a way to obtain a fixed width for each resolution.

I am using RoyalSlider as it has this Visible Nearby mode, the dragging scroll and the gives the possibility to show videos. I am willing to try different scripts or wordpress plugins (even premium) with the same features and am therefore open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use class `.rsActiveSlide` to target the center image.

i.e:

```
.visibleNearby .rsActiveSlide img{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
    -o-transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

Comment: Hey, sorry but I edited now my question to be more clear about the issue.
Applying your solution changes the scale of the image within the container, but not of the container itself and even applying it to .rsContainer, like this:
  .visibleNearby .rsContainer {
  -webkit-transform: scale(2);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
  -o-transform: scale(1.5);
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

Changes the height, but for a 1920x1080px screen the width remains at 1086px instead than 1050px as in the reference site.